# How can I add a child under a child without a specific path?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node named "Chats" under this node there are many chats with a specific ID. Each these Nodes with the ID contain messages. The messages should be added without any specific path. How can I do that?x

I have this following code, but I'm missing one level:

```
final DatabaseReference chat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHATS").child(chatID);
        chat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    chat.child("_s").setValue(sender);
                    chat.child("_r").setValue(reciever);
                    chat.child("_m").setValue(msg);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I need the values to be created in one node as a message. But they are created directly under the chatID. Something like this:

```
final DatabaseReference chat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHATS").child(chatID);
        chat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    chat.CHILD().child("_s").setValue(sender);
                    chat.CHILD().child("_r").setValue(reciever);
                    chat.CHILD().child("_m").setValue(msg);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The structure should look like this:
https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*AHL1ZE8Kt1ctIL2LfZ0z1w.png

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with a combination of ValueEventListener and push().setValu(Object):

```
final String chatID = getChatLeaderID(sender, reciever);
    final DatabaseReference chat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHATS2").child(chatID);
    final HashMap<String, Object> hashMapMsg = new HashMap<>();
    hashMapMsg.put("_s", sender);
    hashMapMsg.put("_r", reciever);
    hashMapMsg.put("_m", msg);
    chat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                chat.push().setValue(hashMapMsg);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```